# Can a dictionary value correspond/be assigned to a function?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have researched on the internet, and I can't find a clear answer to my question. Can a dictionary value be assigned to a local function? For example:

```
def add(x, y):
    sum = x + y
    return sum

dictionary = {'add' : add} # Will this value represent the add function?
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated! :)

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: `return sum([x,y])` would do the same as your function or more simply `return x+y`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the code you posted is correct.  To call the function:

```
dictionary['add'](1, 2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You have no idea how many times I have trashed my code and restarted because I couldn't figure this out. Thanks! :D